# Maximum length for a string for preg_replace() in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I find that if I try to use preg_replace on a very long string, PHP returns an empty page to my browser without showing an error message. I was able to reproduce this bug in my testing environment. What is the maximum length of a string that preg_replace can handle? Is it possible to increase this length?

Comment: "I was able to reproduce this bug in my testing environment" --- show the script here

Comment: I was using the function downloaded from here: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/9/php_tip_how_strip_punctuation_characters_web_page
I remember this problem occurring before when I was using regex to extract data from HTML files, so it's not the regex's problem.

Comment: so what is the question now then?

Comment: The question is why is whether or not preg_replace has a maximum length. If not, why is it killing my script?

Comment: Can you please uncheck my answer so that I could remove it

Comment: Done. 15 chars.

Answer (score 8):

The same happened to me for $pattern matching string over 4M. 
Probably you will have to increase **pcre.backtrack_limit** using ini_set() or editing php.ini.

Check preg for last error:

```
    $retval = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
    if ($retval === null) {
      // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php
      echo preg_last_error();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That's one right way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too, using this regex (i found it somewhere i don't remember):

```
'~\[quote(?:=([^\]]+))?\]((?:(?R)|.)*?)\[/quote\]~s'
```

This is used to replace nested quote BBcodes, using the **(?R)** recursive pattern modifier.

When the string between quotes approaches 300 characters (that is really few), I get a "Reset connexion" in my browser. Nothing in the error logs of Apache or PHP (I am running Wampserver 2.4 with PHP 5.4.16).

It seems that (?R) is an [experimental facility](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).
On this post : [PHP, nested templates in preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912165/php-nested-templates-in-preg-replace), there is a regex with (?R) that is explained in details, which lead me to a solution that works on much longer strings :

```
'%\[quote(?:=([^\]]+))?\]((?:[^[]*(?:\[(?!/?quote(?:=[^\]]+)?\])[^[]*)*|(?R))*)\[/quote\]%x'
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Default value for pcre.backtrack_limit is 1000000. If your string length is above that value you can easily solve it by adding this to the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 5000000);
```

In the code above the max length of the string has been set to 5000000. Adjust based on your own needs.