# Javascript : How to not confuse regex with BB code

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

> **Please Note**
>
> I could find several questions&answers about this but the end result I
>    came up with is :  Dont use regex. So I am posting this question to find
>    a solution to my problem. And maybe an alternative to Regex. I base
>    this on several similar question:
>
> 1. [Replace multiple strings at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once)
> 2. [replace() with RegExp on array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636340/replace-with-regexp-on-array-elements)
> 3. [BB-Code-RegEx in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936622/bb-code-regex-in-javascript)

**Credit to:** user2182349 sor resolving this. See answer below.

I'm am trying to replace my BBcode. I use this function that everyone take for an answer but still is not working for me.

I want to replace things like that:

```
var find = ["[b]", "[/b]", "[i]","[/i]","[u]","[/u]","[N]","[/N]","[c]","[/c]","[li]","[/li]"];
var rep  = ["<b>", "</b>", "<i>","</i>","<u>","</u>","<div class='editNote'>","</div>","<center>","</center>","<li>","</li>",];
```

The [N] tag gets replaced by a span. Actually once i get it to work they will all be span or other tags. i use simple tag right now to be able to get it to work.

**The Function and a few sample string i have tested**

```js
// With escaped
var fEs = ["\[b\]", "\[/b\]","\[i\]", "\[/i\]"];
// Without escape
var f = ["[b]", "[/b]","[i]", "[/i]"];
//replaced with
var r  = ["<b>", "</b>","<i>", "</i>"];
// The string
var string = "this is the [b]first[/b] one and here comes the [b]second[/b] one and when the text contain some b like bacon";

String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
  var replaceString = this;
  var regex; 
  for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
    regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
    replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
  }
  return replaceString;
};

//Ignore the rest. It is just for the snippet to work//////////////////////////////////

 $("#Es").on("click",function (event) {
   string = string.replaceArray(fEs,r)
   $('#result').html(string);
});
 $("#noEs").on("click",function (event) {
    string = string.replaceArray(f,r)
   $('#result').html(string);
});
 $("#reset").on("click",function (event) {
 string = "this is the [b]first[/b] one and here comes the [b]second[/b] one and when the text contain some b like bacon";
   $('#result').html('');
});
```

```css
span{
cursor:pointer
}
div{
height:100px;
width:300px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="Es">Click here to see result with escape</span><br><br>
<span id="noEs">Click here to see result without escape</span><br><br>
<span id="reset">Reset here</span><br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

So the problem seams to be coming from the way i send my BBcode to the regex replacing function. How Should i feed it?

Comment: why do you need a regexp for this? Just use simple string replace

Comment: Because without Regex it replaces only the first instance

Comment: iirc '[' and ']' are special in regexp, so you need to escape them with a '\\'

Comment: and you need to double escape them because its a string. `\\[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex is nice because you can add tags without a lot of code.  If I understand your question correctly, you want to convert the BBCodes to HTML equivalents.  This is one way it could be done with a regex.

```
var s = "this is the [b]first[/b] one and here comes the [b]second[/b] one and when the text contain some b like bacon, and there are [i]icicles[/i]";

var re = /\[(\/?[bi])\]/mg;

console.log (s.replace(re,'<$1>'));
```

If you are willing to allow any BBCodes, you may also use this:

```
var re = /\[(\/?[^\]]+)\]/mg;
```

This will take any **[withsomecharacters]** and turn it into **<withsomecharacters>**, including an optional slash at the beginning.

A more complex implementation would be to use an array of objects.  Each object could have two properties - **in** and **out**.  **in** is the input, **out** is the output, and it can loop through using a string replace for the more complex tags.  The next piece of code could do the regex.

```
var s = "this [N]editnote[/N] is the [b]first[/b] one and here comes the [b]second[/b] one and when the text contain some b like bacon, and there are [i]icicles[/i] and [li]li[/li]";

var p,pairs = [ { "in": "[N]",
    "out": '<div class="editNote">' },
  { "in": "[/N]",
    "out": '</div>' }
];

for (p in pairs) {
        s = s.replace(pairs[p]["in"],pairs[p]["out"]);
}
var re = /\[(\/?[^\]]+)\]/mg;
console.log (s.replace(re,'<$1>'));
```

Comment: But what happen if i have [li] and[i] will both i get confused?

Comment: Even if this would work this totally opposes the idea behind using bbcode, where we want to whitelist the elements we accept

Comment: Its only work with one letter bbcode and wont work with more complex one line   [n][/n]   to <span calss=""></span>

Comment: @MadeInDreams - the second approach will handle multicharacter tags, but it will not translate [n][/n] to <span class=""></span>, I didn't see that in the original question.

Comment: Maybe use a two-regex solution. First convert [n] to <n>, then run a separate regex to convert <n> to <span class="">

Comment: Your second approach is not bad but the thing is that it will make the text less readable while typing it. I use a system with one letter so its not to confusing while typing and inserting tag.

Comment: @user2182349 Yes this is working! Thank you sir. Now i huess i just have to populate the in and out

Comment: After coding it i noticed that it still only replaces only the first occurrence of my tags so i just went custom plain javascript.

Comment: Sorry about that, add the **m**ultiline flag (I updated the code in the answer)